# Self-referencing Regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, context-free-grammar

I want to recognize

```
"Str","Int","[Str]","[Int]","[[Str]]",...
```

I thought I could do something like

```
(Str|Int|\[\1\])
```

where `\1` self references the group. I know from formal language theory that regular expression cannot "count" therefore it wouldn't be possible to keep track of the opening and closing `[` and `]`.

I may need a context free grammar, how would I do this in JS?

Comment: Why do you have "end of string/line" at the start of your pattern?

Comment: So, you have a non-[context free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) solution in mind? Or could you explain by example what kind of answer in JS you don't want?

Comment: unfortunatly JS RegExp sucks,you'll have to write some external logic in js code to do that.

Answer (score 5):

You can use match groups with [RegExp.prototype.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

```
var myString = "[[Str]]";
var myRegexp = /(\[*)Str(\]*)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
if (match[1] !== undefined && match[2] !== undefined && 
    match[1].length === match[2].length) {
   console.log('valid string');
}
```

From MDN:

> If the match succeeds, the exec method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. The returned array has
>   the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was
>   captured.
>
> If the match fails, the exec method returns null.

[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be similarly used.